# Can a WinRT background task be long-lived if within CPU and Network limits?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, background-process

[Microsoft's documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411) states:

> Background tasks are meant to be short-lived tasks that do not consume a lot of resources.

It also says:

> Each app on the lock screen receives 2 seconds of CPU time every 15 minutes, which can be used by all of the background tasks of the app. At the end of 15 minutes, each app on the lock screen receives another 2 seconds of CPU time for use by its background tasks.

- I need to run a background task every two minutes to update my live-tile.
- My app is a lock-screen-app.
- Computation is within the CPU and network usage constraints

Can I create a permanent background task (e.g. something which polls a web service and pulls information, waits and loops) to create a [`OneShot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.oneshot.aspx) `TimeTrigger` every two minutes or is there a better way of doing this?

My concern with the background task option is whether the runtime would deem the task inactive while it was sleeping and close it or something else like there's a limit on the number of times a live tile can be updated within 15 minutes...

Comment: I greatly shortened your question.  I tried to keep the contend while making it easier for potential answerers to quickly grasp what you're trying to accomplish.  Feel free to roll back or improve if I didn't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if by long lived you mean under 25 minutes.

Time triggers cannot execute more frequent than 15 minutes. Creating a OneShot trigger that executes in 2 minutes is, that's an interesting idea and should work. Yes, background tasks can register other background tasks to keep this chain going. Should the user's machine be off when it execs it will queue later.

Having said that, updating your tile that frequently & using a background task is not a wise solution. Because, it is unreliable. Background tasks can be disabled, for one. But every 15 minutes, you are going to exceed your quota. Try using a Scheduled tile instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a little?  It's not immediately clear which question you're answering.

Comment: The question in the title reads: "Can a winrt background task be long-lived if within CPU and Network limits?" The answer is yes. This is an old question, I just didn't want to leave it dead and unanswered.

Comment: The term "short-lived" means "quickly executing each time it's run". It doesn't refer to how long the background task is in effect. Once registered, it stays in effect until unregistered; it might not get to run for any given iteration if it's throttled because of resource limits, but should still be in effect once the quotas are reset.

Comment: Kraig, what's the official wall-clock limit for time background tasks in Windows and in Phone?

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT After I open the page for a question, I pretty much never read the title again, so coming down to an answer and seeing something which directly answers the title but not the body is somewhat confusing for me.  Explicit is pretty much always better than implicit.

Comment: @mydogisbox sounds like we have different habits. Sorry you were confused.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Exactly! Which is why its good to be explicit about what you're answering. (+1 btw)